# Help with \ProvideMathOperator

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, math-operators

In my document I often write

```
c_\mathrm{A}
```

So, to recycle this command for other subscripts other than A, I tried to define a mathematical operator, but it broken

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\ProvideMathOperator[2]{\ifdefined#1\else\DeclareMathOperator{#1}{#2}\fi}    
\ProvideMathOperator{\ci}[1]{c_\mathrm{#1}} % ‹— this
\begin{document}
\[ \ci{A} \]    
\end{document}
```

> ! LaTeX Error:
> Missing \begin{document}.

Any idea?

Comment: Well, you are not defining `\ProvideMathOperator` to define a macro taking an argument, so `\ProvideMathOperator{\ci}[1]{...}` can't work. This being said: why the huge complication? What's wrong with a simple `\newcommand*{\ci}[1]{\mathop{c_\mathrm{#1}}}`?

Comment: Really nice! Thank you!

Comment: note that subscripts should be braced `c_{\mathrm{#1}}`  it seems to work without the braces with `\mathrm` for technical reasons but most commands would fail used that way.

Comment: @campa You also might want `\nolimits` on that thing, to prevent the subscript from appearing centered below.